# Why exception doesn't supress ssl.SSLError

Tags: python, exception

I want to supress all expection by calling:

```
try:
        doSomething()
        doSomething2() # exception is raised
    except Exception:
        print("expection thrown, test should pass!")
```

In doSomething2() there are some exceptions raised like

```
E   ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_CIPHERS_AVAILABLE] no ciphers available (_ssl.c:1076)
```

Why `except Exception` doesn't supress all exceptions ?

Comment: If you really want to catch all exceptions, just use `except:`

Comment: Well, you shouldn't want to suppress all exceptions.

Comment: Then why don't you catch `ssl.SSLError`?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLError), `SSLError` is a subclass of `OSError` which in turn is a child of `Exception`, so this should actually work. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: And also ... according to `print(OSError.__bases__)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo after I removed an expection raising in dosemthing2 I still have /usr/lib/python3.7/selectors.py:42: in _fileobj_to_fd
    raise ValueError("Invalid file descriptor: {}".format(fd))
E   ValueError: Invalid file descriptor: -1
for that what could I use ?

Comment: I really don't know. We need a [mre]... There is nothing ensuring the error even comes from that `try/except` block...

Comment: ... or that it hasn't been caught further up the stack.

Comment: I'm sorry there is just no evidence that this code produces this error. It is more likely that it comes from somewhere else or that your is different. But anyway without a [mre] there is just not much we can do...

Comment: This message doesn't even look like a Python exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have the following code:

```
try:
    doSomething()
    doSomething2() # expection is raised
except Exception:
    print("expection thrown, test should pass!")
```

and ... apparently ... the exception handler is not catching ssl.SSLError.

How can this be?  After all `SSLError` is a subclass of `OSError` which is in turn a subclass of `Exception`.  So, the handler *should* catch an `SSLError`.

Here are all of the *possible* explanations that I can think of:

- `SSLError` is not thrown at all.  We can exclude that as you have shown us evidence that it is thrown.
- The `SSLError` is thrown but caught further up the stack.  For example, if `doSomething2()` does something like this:

  ```
    def something2():
       ...
       try:
           ...
           # attempt to open an HTTPS connection
           ...
       catch OSError:
           # report the exception
  ```

  That exception handler will catch the `SSLError` ... and the outer handler won't ever see it or be able to suppress it.
- The `SSLError` is thrown on a different thread stack.  Uncaught exceptions thrown by one thread don't automatically propagate to a different stack.  Instead, they will just terminate the thread that threw the exception.
- Something has monkey-patched `SSLError` to change its superclass.  This seems so perverse that I'd call this implausible.  But it *may be* technically possible.